# Where exactly do I write define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ) in wp-config file

Tags: php, javascript, debug

would anybody know where I would write WP_DEBUG in wp_config file. I don't see it there.
I would like to check why my javascript is not working. I have enqueued everything with php in the functions.php file. My code is correct, so it must be something else.

Comment: "I would like to check why my javascript is not working" - WP_DEBUG might not show you anything useful here. Can I check you mean that your javascript isn't being enqueued on the page? I think that's all WP_DEBUG might help with, and even then I'm not optimistic. Or is it some other error? e.g. do you have errors in your browser debug console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#example-wp-config-php-for-debugging: *(note though, the "blogging" below is now "publishing")*

> **NOTE:** You must insert this **BEFORE** `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` in the [`wp-config.php`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) file.

So just put it there, like this:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

But actually, depending on the WordPress version that you're using (and your hosting setup or how you installed WordPress), the constant might already be in the `wp-config.php` file, which means you would just need to set the value to `true`, and for example in WordPress 5.8, the default [config template](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/wp-config-sample.php) has the following:

```php
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

See https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/ for further information about editing the `wp-config.php` file.

---

However, I agree with [@Rup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3276/rup), particularly if you've already tried to enable `WP_DEBUG`. So if you're specifically having a JavaScript-specific issue (e.g. you're trying to hide an element and yet it still shows up), then you should use the browser dev tools to debug the issue. You could also try inspecting the raw (or server-generated) HTML source on the page in question and confirm that your JS is indeed being loaded on the page (e.g. if your JS is in `myscript.js` in the theme folder, then check if the HTML contains a `<script>` tag with the `src` value looking something like `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/path/to/myscript.js`).

And if it is, then the browser console would tell you if there's something wrong in your JS, e.g. you may have used `$` (e.g. to access jQuery functions) and yet that variable never defined. Just like if `WP_DEBUG`/debugging is enabled and your PHP attempted to use a variable that was never defined, then the error log file would tell you about that issue.

Comment: I have an error in the console in dev tools that just says: Failed to load resource. the server responded with a status of 404.           clock.png:1

Comment: But, I think that error is because, I did not reference a clock image, but it should still tick, as it does in my text editor.  Am I supposed to put a <script> tag with https://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/path/to/myscript.js). on the page where I have put the html, is that what you mean. I have just put this html on the actual page :  <div id="clockContainer">
        <div id="hour"></div>
        <div id="minute"></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
    </div>

Comment: Basically, if you see `myscript.js` or whatever the actual name is, in the page's HTML source (or the "Sources" tab in Chrome dev tools), then your script is being enqueued correctly. And if your JS (i.e. the JS code in your script file) itself isn't working or causing an error in the browser console, then that's no longer a WordPress issue and instead it is a generic JS issue (which is [not in scope or is off-topic on this stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Thanks Sally. I cannot seem to see the check mark next to your answer. Could you please tell me if I am putting the html correctly on my actual page, as maybe I am supposed to reference the js in the js folder with wordpress, This is what I have done: <script src='https://artandleatherspencer.local/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/js/myscript.js)

<div id="clockContainer">

<div id="hour"></div>

<div id="minute"></div>

<div id="second"></div>

</div>

Comment: As for loading the script, see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ for the proper way to do it in WordPress - try enqueuing the script in the footer, i.e. set the 5th parameter for `wp_enqueue_script()` to `true`. If you need further help in *enqueuing the script*, feel free to post a question on this stack and as always, be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've been to developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics etc, but it doesn't tell me what to do with the html part. You said try inspect raw html source on page in question and confirm that your js is indeed being loaded on the page. Where and how do I check that exactly. Thats why I put <script src=artandleatherspencer.local/wp-content/themes etc before the actual html, as I thought, maybe thats whats needed. Was that the right thing to do, or should I just leave the html there on the actual page. I always thought, that you just put the html on the actual page, and that is all.

Comment: "Where and how do I check that exactly" - you can do that using the browser dev tools or you can also use "hotkeys", e.g. [in Chrome (Windows), press the `Ctrl` and `U` keys simultaneously](https://support.google.com/surveys/answer/6172725?hl=en), and you'd see the HTML source of the page. But for other browsers and regarding how to access the dev tools, please refer to the browser's documentation or search on Google, e.g. "chrome dev tools".

Comment: "I always thought, that you just put the html on the actual page, and that is all" - yes, but WordPress is a CMS or a *dynamic* software which can contain various scripts (and styles) and also content/sections on the page, so conflicts could happen and thus you can't expect your script to simply work just because you've added it to the HTML/page.

Comment: But basically, you can put the HTML to the page and followed by your script, e.g. `<div>my html</div><script>my inline script</script>`; however, a better way particularly for large scripts, is put your script in an external `.js` file, then enqueue/load the file using `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: Also, if you're still having issues with your "clock script", you can post a question on Stack Overflow and include your script code along with an explanation of what is not working for you, e.g. what didn't happen that should've happened. And a tip, be sure to use unique `id` in your HTML to avoid conflicts with WordPress itself, plugins and/or the parent theme, if using a child theme.

Comment: Thanks, I was told that you cannot put a <script> with your html on the page. That is what was confusing me. I will try that. My js script is in the js folder and enqueued correctly etc.

Comment: Of course you can. You just need to do it properly and be careful as to not use scripts from untrusted sources. *So for example*, use the Custom HTML block on Appearance -> Widgets in wp-admin to add both your HTML and script, either inline (if the code is not too lengthy) or link to an external JS file.